# CloudFront Domain Mapping to AWS S3 Bucket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am working on signing the AWS S3 bucket URL with Cloudfront Signing. Here are the steps which I followed to create CloudFront Distribution,

1. Created the origin with mcds_staging_fulltext.s3.amazonaws.com (here mcds_staging_fulltext) is my bucket name.
2. Created the CloudFront Distribution, with origin having "Restrict Bucket Access" to "NO" because i need to access the content through S3 URL too.

Once this is done, I made one of my content to Private and accessed through S3 URL which behaved right with "Access Denied". But When I access this content through my cloudFront Domain URL i am able to view the content , but this should restrict the access too. Am I doing anything wrong here. Kindly Guide.